# Microsoft Word 2013: Table won't break/continue onto next page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I tried setting `Table Properties` -> `Row` -> `Allow Row To Break Across Pages` to checked.

I need the table to continue onto the next page. If I start entering text outside and directly after the table, it continues onto the next page.

I've provided images of the print and draft view so you can see what's going on.

**Print Layout View:**

[image]
**Draft View:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your writing outside the table, did you tried to extend you table to the new page. You can add easily add new rows with TAB key.

[image: Layout Idea]

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Word 2016 now, so I can't check; but I seem to recall that, in Word 2013 and earlier, this could happen if the table's **Text wrapping** property was set to **Around**.